# Группировка и суммирование полей stream api

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть класс:

```java
String branchName;
Integer corporateContractCount;
Integer executorContractCount;
```

Есть список из объектов этого класса `List`.

Как можно с помощью stream api посчитать в сумму элементов `corporateContractCount`, сумму элементов `executorContractCount`, и сгруппировать все по `branchName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью метода: [`Collectors.toMap(,,,)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) можно собрать элементы листа в карту `Map<String, Integer>` и сложить нужные поля:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new SomeClass("Someone", 3, 2));
        list.add(new SomeClass("AnotherOne", 4, 6));
        list.add(new SomeClass("Someone", 1, 4));

        Map<String, Integer> someones = list.stream()
                // собираем из листа карту
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        // ключ - строка
                        e -> e.name,
                        // значение - число,
                        // суммируем два поля
                        e -> e.field1 + e.field2,
                        // суммируем значения
                        // повторяющихся элементов
                        Integer::sum,
                        // имплементация карты
                        // с сортировкой элементов
                        // в порядке добавления
                        LinkedHashMap::new));

        System.out.println(someones); // {Someone=10, AnotherOne=10}
    }
}
```

```java
public class SomeClass {
    String name;
    int field1;
    int field2;

    public SomeClass(String name, int field1, int field2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
}
```

---

См. [Группировка нескольких полей в Stream API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1213908/419011)