# Вывод статистики с помощью Java Streams API

Tags: java, java-stream

Используя Java Stream API Вывеcти статистику по товарам в формате:
//        название товаров - количество разных людей, которые купили хотя бы один товар. (т.е. в лучше случае это будет N - количство созданных человек)

```
public class Person {
String name;
Set<Item> items;
...
// constructors, getters,setters
}

public class Item {
String name;
...
// constructors, getters,setters
}

public static void main() {
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

Set<Item> itemsBoughtVasia = new Set<Item>();
itemsBoutVasia.add("Кефир");
itemsBoutVasia.add("Батон");
itemsBoutVasia.add("Сок");
person.add(new Person("Василий", itemsBoughtVasia ));

Set<Item> itemsBoughtIvan = new Set<Item>();
itemsBoughtIvan.add("Кефир");
itemsBoughtIvan.add("Батон");
person.add(new Person("Иван", itemsBoughtIvan ));

// ...

}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1213615/%d0%93%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-stream-api эта задача элементарная. Моя же намного сложнее. Мне необходимо по подполю, подсчитать количество объектов, которые хранят в себе это поле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package stackOverflow.streamCollectBySet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Person {
    String name;
    Set<Item> items;

    public Person(String name, Set<Item> items) {
        this.name = name;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Set<Item> getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }
}

class Item {
    String name;

    public Item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Item item = (Item) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.name, item.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

        Set<Item> itemsBoughtVasia = new HashSet<>();
        itemsBoughtVasia.add(new Item("Кефир"));
        itemsBoughtVasia.add(new Item("Батон"));
        itemsBoughtVasia.add(new Item("Сок"));
        persons.add(new Person("Василий", itemsBoughtVasia));

        Set<Item> itemsBoughtIvan = new HashSet<>();
        itemsBoughtIvan.add(new Item("Кефир"));
        itemsBoughtIvan.add(new Item("Батон"));
        persons.add(new Person("Иван", itemsBoughtIvan));

        //...
        
        Map<Item, Long> count = persons.stream()
                .map(person -> {
                    Map<Item, Person> itemPersonMap = new HashMap<>();
                    person.getItems()
                            .forEach(item -> itemPersonMap.put(item, person));
                    return itemPersonMap;
                })
                .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.counting()));

        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

---

Output:

> {Батон=2, Кефир=2, Сок=1}

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, Long> collect = persons.stream()
            .flatMap(person -> person.getItems().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getName, Collectors.counting()));

    System.out.println(collect);
```